# The unit count of binary classification in Keras

Tags: keras

In Keras's documentation, for this example:

## For a single-input model with 2 classes (binary classification):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim=100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
data = np.random.random((1000, 100))
labels = np.random.randint(2, size=(1000, 1))

# Train the model, iterating on the data in batches of 32 samples
model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

I have 2 questions for this model:
1) The input is 100 dimensions, so it has 100 features. Why does it say it is 'a single-input model'? what does it mean by 'single-input'?

2) For a binary classification, why the Dense(1, activation=sigmoid) parameter is '1', not '2'? The target is 0 or 1, which represents 2 classes.

Answer (score 2):

1. Here you have 1 input, which is a vector of 100 values. For sure this is 100 features for you, but they packed as single input vector. 
   It is possible that you have 2 or more inputs, for example 1 image tensor + 1 features vectors.
2. It is enough a single value to make a binary classification. As you correctly mentioned, you just return 0 or 1. Sigmoid activation will shrink all values to the [0;1] interval so it can be interpreted as class selection.